# (20.04.3 LTS) USB controllers detected by lsusb and jstest, but not by jstest-gtk or anything else

Tags: usb, udev, gamepad

`lsusb` output:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 04f2:b5a9 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd PDP Wired Controller for Xbox One - Raven Black
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04f3:0755 Elan Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0e6f:02a7 Logic3 PDP Wired Controller for Xbox One - Raven Black
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

`ls -l /dev/input/` output:

```
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root    root       160 févr.  4 13:24 by-id
drwxr-xr-x 2 root    root       340 févr.  4 13:24 by-path
crw-rw---- 1 root    input   13, 64 févr.  4 13:12 event0
crw-rw---- 1 root    input   13, 65 févr.  4 13:12 event1
crw-rw---- 1 root    input   13, 74 févr.  4 13:12 event10
crw-rw---- 1 root    input   13, 75 févr.  4 13:12 event11
crw-rw---- 1 root    input   13, 76 févr.  4 13:12 event12
crw-rw---- 1 root    input   13, 77 févr.  4 13:12 event13
crw-rw---- 1 root    input   13, 78 févr.  4 13:12 event14
crw-rw---- 1 root    input   13, 79 févr.  4 13:12 event15
crw-rw---- 1 root    input   13, 80 févr.  4 13:12 event16
crw-rw---- 1 root    input   13, 81 févr.  4 13:12 event17
crw-rw---- 1 root    input   13, 82 févr.  4 13:12 event18
crw-rw---- 1 root    input   13, 83 févr.  4 13:12 event19
crw-rw---- 1 root    input   13, 66 févr.  4 13:12 event2
crw------- 1 gamepad gamepad 13, 84 févr.  4 13:24 event20
crw-rw---- 1 root    input   13, 67 févr.  4 13:12 event3
crw-rw---- 1 root    input   13, 68 févr.  4 13:12 event4
crw-rw---- 1 root    input   13, 69 févr.  4 13:12 event5
crw-rw---- 1 root    input   13, 70 févr.  4 13:12 event6
crw-rw---- 1 root    input   13, 71 févr.  4 13:12 event7
crw-rw---- 1 root    input   13, 72 févr.  4 13:12 event8
crw-rw---- 1 root    input   13, 73 févr.  4 13:12 event9
crw------- 1 gamepad gamepad 13,  0 févr.  4 13:24 js0
crw-rw---- 1 root    input   13, 63 févr.  4 13:12 mice
crw-rw---- 1 root    input   13, 32 févr.  4 13:12 mouse0
crw-rw---- 1 root    input   13, 33 févr.  4 13:12 mouse1
crw-rw---- 1 root    input   13, 34 févr.  4 13:12 mouse2
crw-rw---- 1 root    input   13, 35 févr.  4 13:12 mouse3
```

**EDIT:** `udevadm info /dev/input/js0` output:

```
P: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0/input/input29/js0
N: input/js0
L: 0
S: input/by-path/pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:2:1.0-joystick
S: input/by-id/usb-Performance_Designed_Products_PDP_Wired_Controller_for_Xbox_One_-_Raven_Black_0000A7133672DBD1-joystick
E: DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0/input/input29/js0
E: DEVNAME=/dev/input/js0
E: MAJOR=13
E: MINOR=0
E: SUBSYSTEM=input
E: USEC_INITIALIZED=757739042
E: ID_INPUT=1
E: ID_INPUT_JOYSTICK=1
E: ID_VENDOR=Performance_Designed_Products
E: ID_VENDOR_ENC=Performance\x20Designed\x20Products
E: ID_VENDOR_ID=0e6f
E: ID_MODEL=PDP_Wired_Controller_for_Xbox_One_-_Raven_Black
E: ID_MODEL_ENC=PDP\x20Wired\x20Controller\x20for\x20Xbox\x20One\x20-\x20Raven\x20Black
E: ID_MODEL_ID=02a7
E: ID_REVISION=010f
E: ID_SERIAL=Performance_Designed_Products_PDP_Wired_Controller_for_Xbox_One_-_Raven_Black_0000A7133672DBD1
E: ID_SERIAL_SHORT=0000A7133672DBD1
E: ID_TYPE=generic
E: ID_BUS=usb
E: ID_USB_INTERFACES=:ff47d0:
E: ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM=00
E: ID_USB_DRIVER=xpad
E: ID_PATH=pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:2:1.0
E: ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_00_14_0-usb-0_2_1_0
E: ID_FOR_SEAT=input-pci-0000_00_14_0-usb-0_2_1_0
E: DEVLINKS=/dev/input/by-path/pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:2:1.0-joystick /dev/input/by-id/usb-Performance_Designed_Products_PDP_Wired_Controller_for_Xbox_One_-_Raven_Black_0000A7133672DBD1-joystick
E: TAGS=:snap_retroarch_retroarch:
```

On a HP x2 Detachable running 64-bit 20.04.3 LTS. `jstest` detects and responds to input without issue.

Following a guide, I had attempted to obtain Joy-Con support via dkms-hid-nintendo and joycond. I did mess more than I should've with udev rules as well as moltengamepad trying to get the Joy-Cons to work (I did not delete anything that wasn't already there). That was unsuccessful, so I removed joycond as well as the module. I later upgraded my system through apt.

I should add that I also installed Steam during the process of trying to get Joy-Cons to work (as Steam apparently implements udev rules for Joy-Con functionality), and accidentally bumped into the PC with my foot some hours after that.

Since then, nothing seems to detect my USB controllers but lsusb and jstest, even after removing Steam. A USB mouse did work without issue.

As an aside which may be related, I also can't seem to get any sound out of the internal speakers anymore, despite the meter in sound settings indicating that sound is being output. Bluetooth and HDMI audio output also work.

I have reasons to believe the problem might be related to udev.

Thanks in advance for your time.

**EDIT:** I booted on the previous kernel and the internal speakers worked, although the gamepad issue is still present. I'm assuming the sound issue is related to the new kernel.

- **UPDATE:** Both issues are absent on live USB. See comments.
- **UPDATE:** Reinstalling the kernel and rebooting did not solve either issue, likewise udev. I'll reinstall my system, but leave this question open in case an answer might be useful to somebody else having this issue.
- **UPDATE:** Reinstall did not solve either issue. Retroarch now only detects input devices that are plugged in after startup, likewise Retroarch cores. Internal speakers work with old kernels. /home/ was kept intact.

Comment: Boot from live media and see if all the hardware is working.

Comment: Done. Audio and at least one gamepad are both working on live USB. Gamepad was a PDP Xbox One controller tested with the Retroarch UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wiped and reinstalled 20.04.3 entirely.

Controllers are detected by jstest-gtk. The Retroarch issue also shows on another 20.04.3 system I have, so it seems to be a bug in the current version of Retroarch itself (or at least the snap). Sound issue still present on the new kernel, but I can always use the old one.

All this to say, this was probably a combination of two unrelated bugs that had nothing to do with my messing about.